# How To Install touchscreen drivers on a raspberry pi

Tags: pi-2, touchscreen

Hello I am trying to install a raspberry pi touchscreen that i bought on ebay on the back it says the brand is KeDei v2.0 i asked the seller and i got the drivers and the instructions say this

1.You can burn the image file to SD card .

2.Installation drive:

The LCD screen and raspberry pie development board connected correctly

copy the drive (LCD_show.tar.gz) to raspberry pi;

Decompression file tar -xzvf LCD_show.tar.gz

Jump into the file cd LCD-show

update system sudo apt-get update

Install driver sudo ./LCD35_v1

then after a few seconds ,the system will reboot

if you want to use the HDMI ,you can use this cmd sudo ./LCD_hdmi

two files i see in it are name Kernel.img and a folder named lib
so i dont know how it will install

but it always says that it is not a directory i know that the file i am trying to install is actually called lcd_35_v2 but even if i replace the only  it it still doesnt work could someone please point me in the right direction??

Comment: Unfortunately you have very little information except for the fact that an automated install process isn't working.  You may need to take time to figure out what it does, analyze this installer (hopefully a shell script) and figure out what is missing.  Or you can see what chips are on the board and go hunting for a known (and probably more portable) driver for them.  There aren't all that many different touch chips out there, and most have published drivers - chances are you vendor didn't write their software from scratch.

Comment: I ordered the same lcd and am currently waiting on the driver from the seller. I can help once I get the tarball and can look at the scripts. Would you mind sharing the driver you have?

Comment: how about mega [link](https://mega.nz/#!u5c0gaBI)

Comment: where you able to install it if so please tell me how